# XCode Error loading .nib

Tags: xcode, nib

I can't load my MainMenu.nib file to my application in XCode. The console log reveals nothing and I'm hoping my .nib file is not corrupted somehow. Please Help!

[image: Screenshot of the error]

```
3/2/12 10:39:29.134 PM Xcode: Exception raised while
                              decoding document objects - 
                              *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]:
                              object cannot be nil
```

Answer (score 0):

It has happened for me, too, after upgrading to Xcode 4.3 some of my .nibs refuse to open.
I filed a bug to Apple a couple of days ago, but still no answer.
Upgraded just now to Xcode 4.3.1, the problems are still there:

```
The document "***.nib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil.
```

As a last resort I'll try to downgrade to Xcode 4.2.
I have tried to open these nibs in a text editor (they are just xml, after all) and they open regularly. They appears intact and healthy. The problem is all in Xcode and it is over my possibilities.

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the ViewController of the nib file together with the nib file and recreate them? There's a couple of way to go around it. Had the same issue and recreated my ViewController without nib file. Then add the content programmatically. Taxing but with more control and flexibility.

Downgrading to 4.2 will prohibit chances to test your app on your device running 5.0.1 (if you have upgraded those devices.